# iPhone SDK - Forwarding touches from a UIViewController to a subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` with a subclass of `UIView` on it called `customSubView1`. Then on customSubView1 I have another subclass of `UIView` called `customSubView2`.

I can capture all the events for touches on all the subviews when I put `touchesBegan/touchesMoved/etc` in the `UIViewController` class. But I want to be able to process them in my custom classes.

I keep reading that the `UIViewController` class needs to 'forward' the touch events to the subviews, but I haven't been able to find any example code to do this. Does anyone have any idea?

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `touches...` methods in your views.

Comment: They are all present, but none of them are called.

Comment: And your views are present, visible, have `userInteractionEnabled = YES` (should be default for straight UIView subclasses)? Are they inside a scrollView, perhaps? Have you tried doing it the most basic way first, to eliminate other causes of error? `CustomViewClass *myCustomTestView = [[CustomViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)]; myCustomView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; myCustomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; [self.view addSubview:myCustomView];` should work.

Comment: Yeah, that was just to cover the bases; sometimes it's the most obvious problems that are overlooked. Are they in a scrollView? The scrollView can "steal" touches. Have you tried my very basic example?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem and I tried the above code CustomViewClass *myCustomTestView = [[CustomViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)]; myCustomView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; myCustomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; [self.view addSubview:myCustomView]; and calls on touchesBegan on the UIView subclass. Was there ever any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set for you `UIView` object `userInteractionEnabled` property:

```
myUIView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```